# How to repeat IF statement to each matching element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, each

I have a number of elements on the page with the same ID. Here's two:

```
<span id="worldwide">United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy</span>

<span id="worldwide">United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy</span>
```

Each element either contains all countries or just one country. These two in the example are both with many countries. I want jquery to check each  if the length is more than 100 and if its true replace all countries with just one word - WORLDWIDE.

This is what I use:

```
<script>
    $("#worldwide").each(function () {
        if ($("#worldwide").text().length > 100) {
            $("#worldwide").text('WORLDWIDE')
        }
    })
</script>
```

This only works to change the first div but it doesn't touch the second. I believe I'm not using the .each function well Please let me know what could be wrong

Comment: ID should be unique.. You cannot have same ID for more than one elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have elements with the same `id` attributes, while elements **should have unique `id`s**. Put classes instead of equal `id` attributes, e.g.

```
<span class="worldwide">...</span>
```

And use this code:

```
$(".worldwide").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length > 100) {
        $(this).text('WORLDWIDE');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/aD7HQ/

Answer (score 1):

ID's are meant to be unique identifiers.  If you have a bunch of elements that you want to behave similarly, use `class` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than one instance of any ID, that's why it's called an ID.

You'd be better off using classes instead.

Also, be aware that JQuery requires the use of a semi-colon at the end of each statement.

```
<span class="worldwide">United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy</span>

<span class="worldwide">United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy United Kingdom Australia United States Lithuania Russia Spain France Portugal Italy</span>


<script>

$(".worldwide").each(function() {


if ($(this).text().length > 100) { $(this).text('WORLDWIDE'); }

});
</script>
```

Comment: _Also, be aware that JQuery requires the use of a semi-colon at the end of each statement._ - **Since when**?

Comment: Trying to find the resource where I first read it. Perhaps I'm wrong. JS doesn't require it, but I was certain JQ did.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library and It cannot enforce any new syntactical rule.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use several elements with the same ID.
If in your case is strictly necesary, you can use this:

```
$('span').each(function(index,element){
    if(element.id == 'worldwide'){
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `.text()` method.

```
$(".worldwide").text(function(i,text){
    return text.length > 100 ? 'WORLDWIDE' : text;
});
```

Also, the obvious ID's must be unique. If you can't make your id's unique or use a class instead, here's an inefficient workaround.

```
$("[id=worldwide]").text(...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't repeat IDs, it goes against Web standards and browser cannot tell wich worldwide you're reffering to, just change them to class and it will work:

```
<span class="worldwide">...</span>
<span class="worldwide">...</span>
```

Each element either contains all countries or just one country. These two in the example are both with many countries. I want jquery to check each if the length is more than 100 and if its true replace all countries with just one word - WORLDWIDE.

This is what I use:

```
<script>
    $(".worldwide").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().length > 100) { $(this).text('WORLDWIDE')}
    })
</script>
```

Notice **$(this)** inside the function.